# How to build shared MuPDF library?

Tags: mupdf

[MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com) by default should build static library, according to bit older [Makfile](http://mupdf.com/repos/mupdf/Makefile) and Internet sources.

I now wanted to build MuPDF shared library which is needed by other project, and it doesn't even include rule for static library in current [Makefile](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=blob;f=Makefile;h=a5fdbc4959b95e6897376b0689b686a8d0668b3b;hb=HEAD).
As can be seen it includes rule only for `libfitz.a` (maybe mupdf library is included in it, I don't know, as except browsing source code I don't see any documentation)

Just in case, I added `-fPIC` in CFLAGS variable in Makerules file, but I didn't get anything except static `libfitz.a` library and various mupdf executables.

How can I build MuPDF shared library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693009